# Lightning style overrides the Visualforce style

Tags: visualforce, css, lightning

I have an old VF page that now needs to be displayed in Lightning. So I checked the checkbox `Available for Salesforce mobile apps and Lightning Pages` for the page.

But the styles seem to override. The page does not use `standardstylesheets` with no `header`. What could I be missing here!

Opting for Lightning Design System here, may need a lot of rework on the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Dreamforce '15, there were several mentions on Roadmap slide decks about auto-styling of classic Visualforce elements (pageBlock, inputField, etc.). There was no date given of when this functionality would be available, but depending on how immediate your need is, waiting it out is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

I use the `Lightning Design System`. It does cause you to not be able to use a lot of `Visualforce` markup. As the element layout is structured differently. But you can then just go with `javascripting remote objects`. You end up with tons more flexibility in what your pages layout like. In addition you get to move a lot of your control off of the server and put it on the client. Page interactions/calculations and such.

You may also want to look in to creating Lightning Applications and Lightning Components.